# Guess the number game: progressing the loop / alert + reset

Tags: javascript, loops, conditional-statements

I want to create a "Guess the numbers game" where you guess a random number within a certain amount of attempts.

I struggle with:

(Must have)
1. Progressing in the loop after the alert (which shows you if your guess was to high, too low, or not a number.

(Nice to have)
2. Resetting the game if you managed to guess the number or ran out of attempts. Resetting means to restore the original amount of guesses and zeroing your attempts. Maybe just a command that refreshes the page.

I'm - after years of break after my first attempts - new to coding.

Here is access to my project: https://glitch.com/~gravel-pyrite

I think this is the relevant loop/conditions engine where I mess up:

```
var rangeMin = 0; //set the min value 
var rangeMax = 10; //set the max value 
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (rangeMax - rangeMin + 1)) + rangeMin;
var counter = 0;
var maxTries = 5;
var remainingTries = maxTries;
var guessedNumbers = [];


document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {

//Displaying min, max and remaining guesses in HTML

  document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = rangeMin;
  document.getElementById('max').innerHTML = rangeMax+"!";
  document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Remaining guesses: "+remainingTries;
  document.getElementById('guessedNumbers').innerHTML = "Your guesses so far: " + guessedNumbers;

  var attempts = +document.getElementById("guessInput").value; // use `+` to make sure your input value is treated as a number and not a string
  guessedNumbers.push(" "+attempts+" ");
  counter++;
  remainingTries--;
  if (counter >= maxTries) { //If running outs of attempts, break out of loop (test for >= to)
    alert("You used up your maximum tries. A new game will start.");
    resetGame();
  } else if (isNaN(attempts)) { //If anything else than a number is entered
    alert(attempts + " is not a number");
  } else if (attempts == randomNumber) { //If guessed correctly
    alert("Awesome! You guessed the number right: " + randomNumber + ". You needed " + attempts + " attempts.");
    resetGame();
  } else if (attempts > randomNumber && counter < maxTries) {
    alert("Your guess " + attempts + " is too high. Guess lower.")
  } else if (attempts < randomNumber && counter < maxTries) {
    alert("Your guess " + attempts + " is too low. Guess higehr.")
  }
}
function resetGame() {
  location.reload(true);
}
```

I expect that after the alerts, I can enter a new value, instead I get stuck in an "alerts loop".

EDIT: I've updated my code now. Reloading the page in after succeeding using up all tries works well.

One thing open: 
document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Remaining guesses: "+remainingTries;
  document.getElementById('guessedNumbers').innerHTML = "Your guesses so far: " + guessedNumbers;

won't only show after the first time the button was submitted.

This is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <h1>Guess what!</h1>
    <p>Guess a number between <span id="min"></span> & <span id="max"></span></p>
    <div>
      <label for="guessInput">Your guess</label>
      <input type="text" id="guessInput">
      <input type="submit" id="submit">
    </div>
    <p id="feedback"></p>
    <p id="guessedNumbers"></p>
    <button onclick="resetGame()">Reset Game</button>
  </body>
```

Comment: Maybe its good to know that I use these variables

`var rangeMin = 0; //set the min value
var rangeMax = 10; //set the max value
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (rangeMax - rangeMin + 1)) + rangeMin;
var counter = 0;
var maxTries = 5;
var remainingTries = maxTries;
var guessedNumbers =[];`

Comment: Not quite, the counter++, remainingTries-- and push(attempts) don't work that way. They stay constant

Answer (score 1):

Adjusted your code
See fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/u0cmtg7j/1/

You don't need a loop, do everything in you submit event.
Also move your DOM manipulation code inside your submit event since you want to update the HTML every time your result changes.

Suggestions:
pack you DOM/HTML manipulation code in a function so that is nice and re-usable.

JS

```
var rangeMin = 0; //set the min value
var rangeMax = 10; //set the max value
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (rangeMax - rangeMin + 1)) + rangeMin;
var counter = 0;
var maxTries = 5;
var remainingTries = maxTries;
var guessedNumbers = [];

//Prompt that asks user to guess a number between x / 10


//Check if number is correct
//If wrong, prompt them to guess again unti they run out of guesses
//If correct, tell them they won, the number of attempts and thank you

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {

  var attempts = document.getElementById("guessInput").value;
  guessedNumbers.push(attempts);
  counter++;
  remainingTries--;
  if (counter > maxTries) { //If running outs of attempts, break out of loop
    alert("You used up your maximum tries.");
    resetGame();
  } else if (isNaN(attempts)) { //If anything else than a number is entered
    alert(attempts + " is not a number");
  } else if (attempts == randomNumber) { //If guessed correctly
    alert("Awesome! You guessed the number right: " + randomNumber + "You needed " + attempts + " attempts.");
    resetGame();
  } else if (attempts > randomNumber && counter < maxTries) {
    alert("Your guess " + attempts + " is too high. Guess lower.")
  } else if (attempts < randomNumber && counter < maxTries) {
    alert("Your guess " + attempts + " is too low. Guess higer.")
  }

  document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = rangeMin;
  document.getElementById('max').innerHTML = rangeMax + "!";
  document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Remainig guesses: " + remainingTries;
  document.getElementById('guessedNumbers').innerHTML = "Your guesses so far: " + guessedNumbers;
}

function resetGame() {

}

//Displaying min, max and remaining guesses in HTML
document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = rangeMin;
document.getElementById('max').innerHTML = rangeMax + "!";
document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Remainig guesses: " + remainingTries;
document.getElementById('guessedNumbers').innerHTML = "Your guesses so far: " + guessedNumbers;
```

HTML

```
<h1>Guess what!</h1>
<p>Guess a number between <span id="min"></span> & <span id="max"></span></p>
<div>
  <label for="guessInput">Your guess</label>
  <input type="text" id="guessInput">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</div>
<p id="feedback"></p>
<p id="guessedNumbers"></p>
<button>Reset Game</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for you to loop within your `onclick` callback method. By looping you're going to keep checking the value in `guessInput` without letting the user change their guess, and so the same `if` block will always run until the player is out of guesses. Instead, you need the click method to control when and how many times the code within your function runs, as it will allow the user to change their guess:

```js
var rangeMin = 0; //set the min value 
var rangeMax = 10; //set the max value 
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (rangeMax - rangeMin + 1)) + rangeMin;
var counter = 0;
var maxTries = 5;
var remainingTries = maxTries;
var guessedNumbers = [];
console.log(randomNumber);
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
  var attempts = +document.getElementById("guessInput").value; // use `+` to make sure your input value is treated as a number and not a string
  guessedNumbers.push(attempts);
  counter++;
  remainingTries--;
  if (counter >= maxTries) { //If running outs of attempts, break out of loop (test for >= to)
    alert("You used up your maximum tries.");
    // resetGame();
  } else if (isNaN(attempts)) { //If anything else than a number is entered
    alert(attempts + " is not a number");
  } else if (attempts == randomNumber) { //If guessed correctly
    alert("Awesome! You guessed the number right: " + randomNumber + "You needed " + attempts + " attempts.");
    //resetGame();
  } else if (attempts > randomNumber && counter < maxTries) {
    alert("Your guess " + attempts + " is too high. Guess lower.")
  } else if (attempts < randomNumber && counter < maxTries) {
    alert("Your guess " + attempts + " is too low. Guess higer.")
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="guessInput" type="number" />
<button id="submit">Guess</button>
```

Comment: Not quite, the counter++, remainingTries-- and push(attempts) don't work that way. They stay constant

Comment: @user2132380 they don't stay constant, they change each time the player makes a new guess (i.e: click the button). You do need to change `if (counter > maxTries)` to `if (counter >= maxTries)` though, I've updated my snippet to include this change

Comment: It works (almost). What I didn't mention is that I manipulate the DOM with this 
```
//Displaying min, max and remaining guesses in HTML

document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = rangeMin;
document.getElementById('max').innerHTML = rangeMax+"!";
document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Remainig guesses: "+remainingTries;
document.getElementById('guessedNumbers').innerHTML = "Your guesses so far: " + guessedNumbers;
```
at the end of the js file. This is what I referred to with my comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is my result. I'm sure things can be improved but all works functionally:

```
var rangeMin = 0; //set the min value 
var rangeMax = 10; //set the max value 
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (rangeMax - rangeMin + 1)) + rangeMin;
var counter = 0;
var maxTries = 5;
var remainingTries = maxTries;
var guessedNumbers = [];

//Displaying min, max and remaining guesses in HTML
document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = rangeMin;
document.getElementById('max').innerHTML = rangeMax+"!";
document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Remainig guesses: "+remainingTries;
document.getElementById('guessedNumbers').innerHTML = "Your guesses so far: " + guessedNumbers;

//The code
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {


  var attempts = +document.getElementById("guessInput").value; // use `+` to make sure your input value is treated as a number and not a string
  guessedNumbers.push(" "+attempts+" ");
  counter++;
  remainingTries--;
  if (counter >= maxTries) { //If running outs of attempts, break out of loop (test for >= to)
    document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Remainig guesses: "+remainingTries;
    document.getElementById('guessedNumbers').innerHTML = "Your guesses so far: " + guessedNumbers;alert("You used up your maximum tries. A new game will start.");
    resetGame();
  } else if (isNaN(attempts)) { //If anything else than a number is entered
    document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Remainig guesses: "+remainingTries;
    document.getElementById('guessedNumbers').innerHTML = "Your guesses so far: " + guessedNumbers;
    alert(attempts + " is not a number");
  } else if (attempts == randomNumber) { //If guessed correctly
    document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Remainig guesses: "+remainingTries;
    document.getElementById('guessedNumbers').innerHTML = "Your guesses so far: " + guessedNumbers;
    alert("Awesome! You guessed the number right: " + randomNumber + ". You needed " + attempts + " attempts.");
    resetGame();
  } else if (attempts > randomNumber && counter < maxTries) {
    document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Remainig guesses: "+remainingTries;
    document.getElementById('guessedNumbers').innerHTML = "Your guesses so far: " + guessedNumbers;
    alert("Your guess " + attempts + " is too high. Guess lower.")
  } else if (attempts < randomNumber && counter < maxTries) {
    document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Remainig guesses: "+remainingTries;
    document.getElementById('guessedNumbers').innerHTML = "Your guesses so far: " + guessedNumbers;
    alert("Your guess " + attempts + " is too low. Guess higehr.")
  }
}

function resetGame() {
  location.reload(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question yesterday, I prepared an answer for you but I found that you have deleted your question :) .

- I use console.log(someVariable); before using it in my code so that I make sure it exists and not null or undefined
- when I did this with your code I found that the variable 'random' existed when I declared it and assign it, but inside the event handler function it becomes 'undefined' because the function is asynchronous
- the working code is the following with simplified logic

  ```
  var rangeMin = 0;
  var rangeMax = 10;
  var remainingGuesses = 4;
  document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = rangeMin;
  document.getElementById('max').innerHTML = rangeMax + "!";
  document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Remainig guesses: " + remainingGuesses;
  var random;
  var guessesMade = 0;//the user hasn't guessed anything yet os we'll declare and assign the variable as zero
  document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function guess() {
  //this is a new guess from the user, lets increase the counter of guesses made and decrease remaining guesses
  guessesMade++;
  remainingGuesses--;
  document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Remainig guesses: " + remainingGuesses;
  //lets assign the variable random a number
      random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (rangeMax - rangeMin + 1)) + rangeMin;
      //lets get what the user guessed
      var userGuess = document.getElementById("guessInput").value;
      if (random == userGuess) {
          alert("CONGRATULATIONS!!! GUESSES NEEDED: " + guessesMade);
          //Resetting:
          remainingGuesses = 4;
          document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Remainig guesses: " + remainingGuesses;
      }
      else {
          //So the user didn't guess it right, there two scenarios:
          //1- user already consumed his chances, we'll alert him about it and reset the game
          //2- user still has guesses to make, we will test and advise him
          if (remainingGuesses == 0) {
              // scenario (1-)
              alert("SORRY, YOUR RAN OUT OF GUESSES. LETS PLAY AGAIN!");
              remainingGuesses = 4;
              document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Remainig guesses: " + remainingGuesses;
          }
          else {
              //scenario (2-)
              //we will check the value of his guess and advise him
              if (random > userGuess) {
                  alert("SORRY, YOUR GUESS " + userGuess + " IS SMALLER THEN THE NUMBER IN QUESTION." + "\n" + "CHOOSE A HIGHER NUMBER");
                  document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Remainig guesses: " + remainingGuesses;
              }
              else if (random < userGuess) {
                  alert("SORRY, YOUR GUESS " + userGuess + " IS HIGHER THEN THE NUMBER IN QUESTION." + "\n" + "CHOOSE A SMALLER NUMBER");
                  document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = "Remainig guesses: " + remainingGuesses;
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```